# How do I flatten Json in Azure Datafactory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to ingest the following in Postgres table. I have a Copy data set up but Groups and Questions are getting null values. What am I missing in my mapping? Checklists can have one or more groups. And, each group can have one or more qeustions.

The source of the data is an Api. Is there a better way to flatten the json string and then ingest it in the table?

[image]

```
{
"checklists": [
    {
        "id": "71Pbxb42",
        "name": "Emergency Planning Checklist",
        "checklist_template_id": "2QyMrEy2",
        "modified_date": "2022-12-12T03:31:14Z",
        "created_date": "2022-12-12T03:31:14Z",
        "total": 13.00,
        "max_total": 13.00,
        "franchisee": {
            "id": "GYNnZEAW",
            "name": "Kindergartens - Huntly",
            "external_id": "CNIKA_5179"
        },
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": "WoNgLAQG",
                "checklist_template_group_id": "73evDRBW",
                "name": "Early childhood services and Mātauranga Ake ",
                "attachments": [],
                "group_score": 13.00,
                "max_score": 13.00,
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "id": "GzRlJk4G",
                        "question_type": "select",
                        "question": "Team roles and responsibilities are clarified in the Emergency Procedure ",
                        "select": "Yes",
                        "score": 1.00,
                        "max_score": 1.00,
                        "comment": "",
                        "checklist_template_question_id": "G66bDbmG",
                        
                            },
                    {
                        "id": "LzRlJm4G",
                        "question_type": "select",
                        "question": "Team roles and responsibilities are clarified in the Emergency Procedure ",
                        "select": "Yes",
                        "score": 1.00,
                        "max_score": 1.00,
                        "comment": "",
                        "checklist_template_question_id": "G66bDbmG",
                        
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In copy activity, you cannot flatten the nested objects which are in the nested Json. In this case, you can use dataflow to flatten the data. Below is the approach.

- You can use rest dataset as a source in data flow source transformation.
- Then take the flatten transformation and give the unroll by `[]checklists.group.question`.

[image]

- You can take the input columns and map it with the output columns in mapping of flatten settings. In this demo, I took four input columns and mapped it to output columns. Below is the mapping settings.

```
checklistsid = checklists.id,
franchiseid = checklists.franchisee.id,
groupsid = checklists.groups.id,
questionid = checklists.groups.questions.id
```

[image]

- Take the PostgreSQL dataset as a sink dataset.
- By this way, you can flatten the Json and copy it to PostgreSQL.